# Automated WAN IP forwarding

Tags: bash, cron

I want to cronjob my script that does :

1. Get my WAN adress and write it to a file.
2. Compare the existent file with the new one.
3. If the new one is different from the old one, it should then email it to me.
4. And if they differ it should overwrite the old one with the new one.

But it actually doesn't work and I don't know why.

It e-mails me the WAN2.txt file whether it's the same or not, and it doesn't overwrite it either.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                 

wan1=/home/user/Scripts/wanip.txt                        
wan2=/home/user/Scripts/wanip2.txt                       


dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com>$wan2    

if [ "$wan1" != "$wan2" ]                                   

then                                                        
        /usr/bin/sendEmail -f showname@example.com -t sendto@example.com -u Wanip -m "hallo" -s smtp.example.com:587 -xu user -xp passwort -a $wan2

elif [ "$wan1" != "$wan2" ]                                 

then                                                        
        $wan2>$wan1                                         

else exit                                                   

fi
```

Comment: "_it actually doesn't work_" What do you mean? Do you get an error? What does it say?

Comment: Your script doesn't work or you can't cron it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing variables, not contents of the files.

Variable `$wan1`, in your case, will never hold the same value as `$wan2`, thus your script will always send you an e-mail. Use `cmp`, `diff` etc. for comparing files.

Also, your `if` and `elif` have the same condition, meaning that when `if` gets triggered, your `elif` doesn't.

`$wan1 > $wan2` is also incorrect as it would search for a **program** called `/home/user/Scripts/wanip.txt` and redirect the output to `/home/user/Scripts/wanip2.txt`. Use `cp` to overwrite or change your line to `cat "$wan2" > "$wan1"`.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                 

wan1=/home/user/Scripts/wanip.txt                        
wan2=/home/user/Scripts/wanip2.txt                       

dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com > "$wan2"    

if ! cmp --quiet "$wan1" "$wan2"; then                                                        
   /usr/bin/sendEmail -f showname@example.com -t sendto@example.com -u Wanip -m "hallo" -s smtp.example.com:587 -xu user -xp passwort -a "$wan2"  
   cp -f "$wan2" "$wan1"                                                                                         
fi
```

Comment: THX this one worked for me. But in the first place I didn't have set it with variables, just with the full path and it didn't work ether.

Comment: You cannot use `[ path != path2 ]` to compare files. It compares strings. And the filepaths are different in your case so your condition always got triggered. You need to use `cmp` or such to compare files.